# iOS: Running a method from an IBAction

Tags: ios

What I have is an iPhone app that populates a UIpickerView with an array.  I have two arrays.  One of which has troops in it, another has a corresponding ip address in it for each troop.  I have my pickerView method written but I cannot figure out how to execute the pickerView method via IBAction.  Here is what I have.

The button on my app:

```
-(IBAction)btnConnect:(id)sender
{

}
```

The method I'm trying to get the button to perform:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:         (NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *populateTroops = [troops objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *PopulateURLS = [URLArray objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *pathComponentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/RadioFeed.mp3",    populateTroops, PopulateURLS];
    myFeed.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [myFeed loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle    mainBundle] resourcePath]
                                                                             stringByAppendingPathComponent:pathComponentString]]]];
}
```

Can someone please help me?  When the user clicks the button depending on what they have selected in the pickerView they will be sent to the proper url assigned to the troop.  I have the webView, pickerView and button in the .xib file.  Upon compile I have no errors of any sort.  Thanks.

Comment: Move the code to the `btnConnect:` method replace `row` with `[self.myPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]`.

Comment: It's just code - one method calling another.  It should be obvious.